Stream anyMatch accept an method reference not implement Predicate
Stream.anyMatch is defined as:
boolean anyMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate)

I created a new Class as follows:
class ClassA  {    
    public boolean anyMethodName(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Integer;
    }
}

Then I can run following:
List<String> durunitList = Arrays.asList("h", "d", "w", "m", "y");
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
System.out.println(durunitList.stream().peek(System.out::println).anyMatch(classA::anyMethodName));

But in my ClassA, I haven't implemented Predicate or its functional method:
boolean test(T t)

Why can classA::anyMethodName be stil passed to Stream.anyMatch(...)?

How did you come up with the expression classA::anyMethodName whose only purpose is to enable what you are now surprised about? Why are you surprised by the possibility of using a method reference where a predicate is expected while glossing over the fact that you are also using System.out::println where a Consumer is expected?

Java 8 added the ability for interfaces to be "functional interfaces" whenever an interface has one abstract method. If they are, the compiler allows you to use a method (either as a lambda or a method reference classA::anyMethodName) like as though it were an instance of that interface, by creating an anonymous class for you (assuming that it has the same return type / parameters).
Predicate is a functional interface, and as such allows you to directly use your classA::anyMethodName method as though it were an instance of Predicate.
In the end, your code effectively gets translated into:
List<String> durunitList = Arrays.asList("h", "d", "w", "m", "y");
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
System.out.println(durunitList.stream().peek(System.out::println).anyMatch(new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String o) {
        return classA.anyMethodName(o);
    }    
}));

ClassA isn't ever casted to Predicate (as it's not a predicate...), but a new anonymous class that does implement Predicate simply calls classA.anyMethodName behind the scenes.

But my ClassA definition has NO the keyword "implements Predicate", why the compiler still treats ClassA is an implementation of Interface Predicate?

ClassA is never ever treated as or casted to a Predicate. Notice how in the (example) final code, a new anonymous class is created that does implement Predicate (hence @Override public boolean test), which then calls your classA.anyMethodName method.

your second sentence is misleading, the @FunctionalInterface ANNOTATION is not required for that - the annotation is, as stated in the link you supplied, "An informative annotation" (similar to @Override, not required, but checked if present) -- Java Language Specification 9.8. Functional Interfaces: "A functional interface is an interface that is not declared sealed and has just one abstract method (aside from the methods of Object), and thus represents a single function contract."

@user85421 ty for the heads up, I'll rewrite that part! (also I called them attributes b/c I had c# on the brain lol)
